# why the if statement did not print out the string? cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, string, printing

I want to print the even and odd in a string rather than in binary for true false | 1 / 0;
Why the output still print the boolean value?

```
int main() {
    printf("enter the two numbers\n");
    int a;
    int b;
    cin >> a >> b;

    string arr[9] = {"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"}; 
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
    {
        if(i <=9){
           cout << arr[i-1] << "\n";
        }else{
           cout << ( i%2 == 0)? "even" : "odd"; // print out 1/0 but did not print out the even and odd
           cout << "\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
enter the two numbers
9 16
nine
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
```

Comment: Compiler warnings are helpful: "warning: third operand of conditional expression has no effect" (https://wandbox.org/permlink/2mCAy4nyNZ5LJ93x).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing parens to enclose the expression.  The ternary has lower precedence than `<<`.

```
cout << (( i%2 == 0)? "even" : "odd");
```

Comment: Also, the parentheses around `i%2 == 0` aren't needed.

Comment: @PeteBecker  True, but those of us who have to look at the chart on our wall every time would be tempted to put them in anyway.

Comment: @stark -- (I (understand (what (you're talking about)))).